# Generate base64 string of an image to use in data URI

Tags: java, html, image, base64, data-uri

How to generate base64 string of an image to use in data URI?

I have an Base64 image encoding issue that I hope someone can help with. I'm trying to use data uri in my web page (ie `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw..."/>` with `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` v1.8 generating the base64 string of png image.

To generate the base64 string I have used:

```
Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageFile)
```

The problem is the browser cannot render the image. I compared this generated string with one that works and I noticed the differences are the Apache Base64 version has "_" and "-" characters instead of "/" and "+". From the internet I see there are different Base64 formats so I assume Apache's implementation is not compatible with the browsers.

So I was wondering is there a library that implements the base64 format that would be appropriate for my purposes? My current fix is to just replace the characters but I would rather use a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the javadoc of the [Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafe%28byte%5B%5D%29) method, that seems to be by design.  Check out the link I provided, it says this in the javadoc:

> Encodes binary data using a URL-safe variation of the base64 algorithm but does not chunk the output. **The url-safe variation emits - and _ instead of + and / characters. Note: no padding is added.**

So you want to make sure you use the url-unsafe variation. That's the method called [encodeBase64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64%28byte%5B%5D%29).  Use this method instead:

```
Base64.encodeBase64(imageFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ConvertToBase64 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] b = "Ha".getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("bytes: " + b.length);
        javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(b);  
    }
}
```