# I want to send image from java server to android using image url

Tags: java, image, image-uploading

I want to make image url from my image path like,`http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg`.
I stored image in my local server `/home/image/a.jpg`

Comment: Sounds like a wonderful goal, if you ask me.  But I'm not sure what specifically you're *asking* about, though.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515783/generate-base64-string-of-an-image-to-use-in-data-uri

Comment: I want to send image from java server to android.i stored image path in database like /home/image/a.jpg.In stead of that i want to make an url like http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg ie on clicking the url i can see the image on browser.is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can install a web server on the system that has the images, change this web server's root directory to the directory in which you've stored the images. Then, from the android app, download the image using a URL that you can construct using the web server's address and the path to the image relative to the web server's root directory.  Ex: if the root directory is `/home/image/` the URL will be: `www.example.com/a.jpg`

Comment: Hi...i am using linode server with ip 139.162.19.227 .I have copied one image into root folder.but i can not get image using  this url 139.162.19.227/root/images.jpg.what should i do to get that  image on browser?

Comment: @RakeshR What you got now is a VPS (Virtual Private Server) in order to make your image accessible through an URL you will need to install a Web Server on this system (on the VPS) something like Apache HTTP Server. The images should go into the Apache's root folder not into the VPS root folder.

Comment: This is a guide for installing Apache on CentOS https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/apache-2-web-server-on-centos-6

Comment: I have copied image to apache tomcat root folder.how to get its url?

Comment: @RakeshR your web server seems to be offline, have you started it ? Tomcat has some dependencies, you need Java in order to run it.

Comment: I just copied one image into my tomcat root folder in local system,then restarted  my tomcat.My ip address is  192.168.0.32. I am using this url http://192.168.0.32:8080/root/images.jpg to get that image but shows 404 image not found exception?

Comment: @RakeshR Tomcat seems to be offline on that system (192.168.0.32). Tomcat applications directory is usually at `/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps`, just place your images into the `ROOT` directory at that location and start Tomcat.